# IEnumerator repeating action

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

In unity I was making an IEnumerator that would wait then take you to another scene. Then after that scene you press play to go to another scene. But after pressing play it takes you back to the scene after another 10 seconds pass. How would I stop this from looping?

```
using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class Anim : MonoBehaviour
    {
        IEnumerator Timer()
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
            }
        
        void Start()
        {
            StartCoroutine(Timer());
        }
        
    }
```

I tried putting it in a if statement with a variable that changes after it does it one time. This failed and gave me an error. I expected it to not loop. And It did loop.

Comment: If you are using the Anim Gameobject again in the scene you are loading then the code will run again since everything gets loaded again.

Comment: what is the purpose of using a IEnumerator ? it wouldn't be easier if you delete it  and trying to use a Task?

Comment: I'm using the IEnumerator to wait an amount of time what other way could I use to wait time because I don't know it.

Comment: Are you looking for `PeriodicTimer`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: If this code runs every time the scene is loaded. Yes. 10s later it will load again.

Comment: As @dmitry-bychenko told , PeriodicTimer will work for your requiremnt. Or  Task.Delay

Answer (score -1):

as the comments say, if u want to make this every scene don't make several objects just make this script persist *DontDestroyOnLoad()*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).